# Why are there so many binders and asynctasks in my thread group list? How are they managed?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-binder, threadgroup

**The setup:**  I have service class and two activities that bind to it.  The first is the main UI activity that calls on

```
startService(intent);
bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE).
```

The second activity only calls on 
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE).

Both calls 
    unbindService(mConnection) in onStop().

There's a button call "button A" on the main UI that when press will pass an arrayList to a method on the service.  The method in the service then starts a new static thread to process this arrayList.  The new thread also has a static message handler to communicate with the methods in the service.  The second activity calls on the service to perform a calculation and then saves the result in a database.

I only explicitly declared one thread in the service.  So I expect 2 threads total including the main thread and I only expect two binders since I only have two activities that bind to the service.  However, when I do a Thread.activeCount() in onCreate of main UI, I initially get 3 threads.  Later I get 4 threads, followed by 9 threads and 11 threads as I proceed in the manner described below.

**Here's the questions.**
**How are the binders and asynctasks added to my thread group's list?**  Why do they keep expanding?  I am concerned about battery consumption, will more threads mean more battery consumption?  Or it just does the work faster and these automatically generated threads will garbage collect themselves?  Do I have any memory leaks?  Can I control how these threads are spawned?

I didn't find much documentation on this.  Anyone understand this matter please let me know.

**First run of the app, in onCreate of main UI:**

ThreadGroup ctg = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
ctg.list();

The list shows:

```
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[main,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Thread-5,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Binder_1,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Binder_2,5,main]
```

I know main, Binder_1, Binder_2 are the 3 active threads.  **I reorient my phone, logcat shows:**

```
MainActivity   onStop unbindService
MainActivity   onDestroy() plus debuginfo --Pid is 18606, threadid is 18606, there are 4 threads
MainActivity   onCreate() plus debuginfo --Pid is 18606, threadid is 18606, there are 4 threads
I/System.out(18606): java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxPriority=10]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[main,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Thread-5,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Binder_1,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Binder_2,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Binder_3,5,main]
Service   onStartCommand() 2--Pid is 18606, threadid is 18606, there are 4 threads
```

**Then I press "button A" on main UI to process arraylist by creating a new thread, then I get 11 threads.**  Logcat shows:

```
D/Service(18606): in processRuleOnArrayList -- ACTUALLY MADE A NEW THREAD
D/BoundService(18606): processRuleOnArrayList(): --Pid is 18606, process threadid is 18606, service     threadid is 2930, service threadname is serviceName_0, there are 11 threads
D/Service(18606): processRuleOnArrayList(): service thread's threadGroup main, main thread's threadGroup java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxPriority=10]
I/System.out(18606): java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxPriority=10]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[main,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Thread-5,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Binder_1,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Binder_2,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Binder_3,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[AsyncTask #1,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[AsyncTask #2,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[AsyncTask #3,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[AsyncTask #4,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[AsyncTask #5,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[Binder_4,5,main]
I/System.out(18606):     Thread[serviceName_0,5,main]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep references to the AsyncTasks and service bindings you create and reuse them (or destroy them if they need to be recreated).

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and search for onSaveInstanceState.